# Context menu in Chrome - two actions (left/right click on item menu)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

I want to create an extension for chrome browsers: item menu in context menu with two different actions when you use left or right click on item menu.
For Firefox it can be realized, but for Chrome? How?

[image]

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'do action (left cl. - first, right cl. - second)',
        id: 'test',
        contexts: ['link'],
    });
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "test") {
        console.log("first action completed")
    }
});
```

Comment: You'll need to (and should anyway imo) create two separate items.

Comment: @DanielHerr So it's only possible in Firefox?

Comment: Yes. It's impossible in Chrome.

Comment: @DanielHerr As it is apparently the season for answering in comments, I'm gonna steal _all the reputation_. All of it. Mwahahahaha. Oh wait, no, I'll make that a CW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinguishing between two clicks in a *context menu* is impossible in Chrome.

To be fair, it's a very confusing idea, I don't think people expect that from a context menu UI.

Now, clicking with a modifier key is something more common (e.g. Delete vs Shift+Delete in a file manager), but Chrome does not support it either.

You can see the full list of data available [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#property-onClicked-callback).

Comment: Firefox does support [modifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/OnClickData) though.